# Lazy-Eval Dependency Injection for Value Provider (Unity, Structure Map, Ninject...)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, lazy-loading, ioc-container

Instead of injecting a behavorial dependency, I want to inject data dependencies - where the data comes from a database or other service calls.  To achieve this, my first step would be to make type-to-delegate bindings instead of type-to-type bindings.  So far so good, I think most .net IOC containers can do that.

But I expect the many data-injections to create unwanted latency, since it means many round-trips to the data store.  I would rather that all data objects to be injected would be fetched in a single request.

I'd like to know if there is a framework or library out there for this, or sample code.

I presume a framework or library would fulfill my need by evolving my prior proposal so that the delegate bindings...

1. each place a data request into a thread-local-storage queue.
2. return only types that are `Lazy< T >`.

After the IOC container is done injecting all the `Lazy< T >` types, invariably program execution will execute one of the `Lazy< T >.Value` delegates.  When that happens, the entire queue of data requests are sent simultaneously and populated simultaneously into a hash table or dictionary inside TLS.  Thus the first `Lazy< T >.Value` hit would be slow, but all the other `Lazy< T >` items that were part of the IOC container's injection tree would then execute quickly.

Thoughts on this proposed approach?  Any libraries do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting data directly into consumers that need it might work in some circumstances, but in most cases it is the consumer who determines what data he needs, by querying this data (asking for data using supplied arguments).

For those few cases that data can be injected directly (you can see them as parameterless queries), injecting data directly would make your DI configuration extremely complex. Take for instance a consumer that depends on the current time in the system. You could inject a `DateTime` into the consumer (or even a `Lazy<DateTime>`). Another consumer might need the date of birth of the current user, so this consumer also depends on an `DateTime`. But now you got ambiguity in the system, since the `DateTime` dependency has two meanings. DI containers are bad in handling this, and to resolve this, you will have to tell the container explicitly what `DateTime` means for each consumer that needs it. This results in a brittle configuration that is hard to contain.

For this latter case (the parameterless queries), the solution is to define unambiguous interfaces that can be resolved. In the example above you can define an `ITimeProvider` interface and a `IUserContext` interface. Each consumer can take a dependency on the correct interface.

For the former case (the parameterized queries), you don't need a framework for this; you need proper design.

You are talking about querying a database and web service and need a way to cache the returned data. So what you need is an abstraction for defining queries, and do it in a way that you can apply caching and other [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) to them, in a way that is pluggable and saves you from having to make any changes to your code.

An effective way to do this is by defining a interface that defines the query object (the input parameters of the query) + the return type, and an interface that defines the logic that handles that query:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> 
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

With these abstractions you can define a query object like this:

```
public class FindUsersBySearchTextQuery : IQuery<User[]>
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeInactiveUsers { get; set; }
}
```

This object defines a query that finds users by a search text and allows inclusion or exclusion of inactive users, and the query result is an array of `User` objects.

The logic that executes this query can be implemented as follows:

```
public class FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler
    : IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]>
{
    private readonly NorthwindUnitOfWork db;

    public FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler(
        NorthwindUnitOfWork db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public User[] Handle(FindUsersBySearchTextQuery query)
    {
        return (
            from user in this.db.Users
            where user.Name.Contains(query.SearchText)
            where user.IsActive || query.IncludeInactiveUsers
            select user)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

And why exactly does this solve the problem you have? This solves your problem because consumers can depend on the `IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]>` interface, while you can wrap `IQueryHandler<T>` implementations with [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), without anyone to know. Writing a decorator that caches the result in the tread-local stogage is a no-brainer:

```
public class TlsCachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    where TResult : class
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static TResult cache;

    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decorated;

    public ValidationQueryHandlerDecorator(
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        return cache ?? (cache = this.decorated.Handle(query));
    }
}
```

Any solid DI container allows you to register these decorators and allow you to register decorators conditional (based on the type information of the decorated type). This allows you to place this caching decorator only on types that can safely be cached (according to your conditions).

You can find more information about this model in this article: [Meanwhile… on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).